# How to edit tomcat-users.xml file?

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, whm

I want to edit tomcat-users.xml but somehow I am not able to open it, download it, change ownership.

I tried following command to change ownership:-

```
chown root tomcat-users.xml
```

I tried following command to change permission:-

```
 chmod 777 tomcat-users.xml
```

But its not working it gives me error

```
chmod: changing permissions of `tomcat-users.xml': Operation not permitted
chown: changing ownership of `tomcat-users.xml': Operation not permitted
```

[image]

Comment: What is your user? Can we assume you're not `root`?

Comment: try: sudo chmod 777 tomcat-users.xml

Comment: check the edits @JonSurrell

Comment: @alnet its the same for that.. we don't have to add sudo in this

Comment: Based on your screenshot, that file is only writable by user `tomcat` (or `root`). You will need to find a way to modify that file as one of those users.

Comment: you mean the username from which I used to login ? @JonSurrell

Comment: You do have to add sudo, but your sudo failed for other reason (error: Command not found). Anyway, this says to need to be root, which is what sudo will do when it works: http://superuser.com/questions/697608/chown-operation-not-permitted

Comment: @Andreas is there a way ? or how to get root access ? I purchase hosting from a company but they are not helping in changing that

Comment: Yes, you will need to be logged in as a user who has permissions to write the file (`tomcat` or `root`). As mentioned in other comments, the `sudo` command effectively executes a command as `root`, but you appear not to have access to `sudo`, and your user may or may not be able to use `sudo` anyways.